# PayPal - Payer is not identified

Tags: api, magento, paypal, proxy, paypal-sandbox

I'm currently working on a project who use Magento and PayPal. I have configured the PayPal settings with a sandbox which I use on multiple projects, when I choose to pay with PayPal on the sandbox mode, I can pay correctly but when I got redirected to the shop I got the error "Payer is not identified" and cannot proceed the order.
The shop is under a proxy who is configured in PayPal too. The email to pay is a one I use on other project too and I do not have problem.
Any hint or idea ? Proxy related ?

Comment: try contact paypal now only......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find out it was on the Call of the API NVP, it was a conflict with the proxy where sometimes the answer of the call got an array of 4 (to send) and an array of 3 (to get).

In `app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Model\Api\Nvp.php` line 973

I have changed

```
$response = preg_split('/^\r?$/m', $response, 2);
$response = trim($response[1]);
$response = $this->_deformatNVP($response);
```

to

```
$answer = preg_split('/^\r?$/m', $response, 4);
if($answer[3]) {
    $response = preg_split('/^\r?$/m', $response, 4);
    $response = trim($response[3]);
} else {
    $response = preg_split('/^\r?$/m', $response, 3);
    $response = trim($response[2]);
}
$response = $this->_deformatNVP($response);
```

Of course, I have overrided the Class to keep the core code clean.

Magento version: 1.9.2.4

Hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be a problem with one of Magentos patches not being applied correctly
make sure your system has this file in place
/lib/Unserialize/Reader/Null.php

its part of this patch SUPEE-8788